# ajaxStart does not work on Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have ajaxStart event that is working fine for ajax loads. But when I do a POST is not working at all.

Here the code that is always render per all pages.

```
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        hideIcon();
        if (stepState !== '' && stepState !== CONSTANTS.DISABLED_FORM) {
            enableElement();
        }
    });
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        showIcon();
        disableElement();
    });
```

And here my post.

```
     var sendRequest = function (url, data) {
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function( options ) {
        options.global = true;
    });
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            applicationAlerts.showStatus(data);
            loadDocumentGroup();
        }
    });
};
```

I follow this tickets here https://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajaxstart-is-not-working, but in my case does not work.

I´m using JQuery 1.11

Any suggestion?. Thanks!

Comment: In the jQuery documentation i found this hint:
`If $.ajax() or $.ajaxSetup() is called with the global option set to false, the .ajaxStart() method will not fire.`
Does that help you?

Comment: Yes that was I read and try without any success

Answer (score 0):

I think you made mistake in `ajax` function.Try to change like this

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
.....
});
```

There is no Parameter like `method` in `ajax` Request.You need to use `type` parameter to specify the type of Request.(GET OR POST)

Hope it will works!. Thanks

Comment: You can use method or type. The transaction works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery version 1.9 or later use:

```
method: "POST"
```

or

```
type: "POST"
```

if the version is below 1.9, only use:

```
type: "POST"
```

For your [reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)